# closed issues are not marked as close in JIRA

Tags: jira, transition

Jira Version: **3.13.5**

I've on my Dashboard in JIRA a section which display all open issues assigned to me. 
But in this list are also some already closed issues.

So I had a look at the **workflow**. 
I just get 1 close transition. I add under "Post Functions" the following:

```
Set issue status to the linked status of the destination workflow step.
— THEN
Add a comment to an issue if one is entered during a transition.
— THEN
Update change history for an issue and store the issue in the database.
— THEN
Re-index an issue to keep indexes in sync with the database.
— THEN
Fire a Issue Closed event that can be processed by the listeners.
```

But it doesn't work! All issues which are closed aren't marked as close!

Does anyone know where I can find this settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Assigned to me" app on the Dashboard doesn't show issues **that are assigned to you and Open**.
It shows issues that **are assigned to you and have a status of Unresolved**.

I suspect that your post-function does not do this. I currently have the same problem with JIRA 5.03 and a Greenhopper automatically generated workflow. I've also filed an issue with the Atlassian Support. 
Check your resolution status, if it is unresolved you've found your problem.

Comment: great, thats my problem! thanks. 
but how can i change the resolution with the transition.
in "Add" i found nothing which change it to resolved...